# c# listview sort on button click

Tags: c#, sorting, button, onclick

I want to sort column 1 on button5_click, but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

The sort function is currently set on listview column click and I get the column id by ColumnClickEventArgs but I dont know how to set the column id manually.

Sorting code:

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void listView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column == lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn)
        {
            if (lvwColumnSorter.Order == SortOrder.Ascending)
            {
                lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Descending;
            }
            else
            {
                lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn = e.Column;
            lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
        }
        this.listView1.Sort();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are saying that you want to sort column 1 then replace **e.Column** by **0**. Here **e.Column** will give the column index on which we clicked. But as you want the 1st column, its index will be 0 and so you can place **0** instead of that.